# Discuss the continuity of $\sqrt{|xy|}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I know that $\sqrt{|xy|}$ is continuous function but i'm not getting how to prove this. Do i have to use polar coordinates or to select any path like y=mx to check the continuity??

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put braces around the stuff that goes under the square root sign, the top bar expands to cover it.  Check my edit.

Comment: You just have to prove $xy$ is continuous. The rest follows by composition.

Comment: Check out this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339289/continuous-function-proof-by-definition

Comment: Prove that if f and g are continuous real functions then h(x,y)=f(x)g(y) is continuous using standard epsilon-delta methods.

Answer (score 3):

As you say: let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, where $r>0$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{|xy|} &=& \sqrt{|r^2\cdot \cos\theta\sin\theta|}\\ \\
&=& \sqrt{\left|r^2\cdot \frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}\right|}\\ \\
&=& \frac{r}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{|\sin 2\theta|}
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $0\le |\sin 2 \theta| \le 1$ for all $\theta$, it follows that as $r \to 0$, $\sqrt{|xy|} \to 0$ for all $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

By the [*inequality of arithmetic-geometric means*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) $$\sqrt{|xy|}\leq\frac{|x|+|y|}{2}.$$
Now use the fact that $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ if and only if $|x|+|y|\to0$ to conclude that $\sqrt{|xy|}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.